# Is there a Python equivalent to `bash -x`?

Tags: python, bash

I'd like to 'debug' a Python script, but instead of implementing logging, just view the lines in stdout before execution.

Comment: Using a Python debugger maybe? Most IDEs have one.

Comment: You can have a look at [trace](https://pymotw.com/2/trace/) .

Comment: [PDB](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) might be of help.